# React Native: Fetch Stripe API

Tags: react-native, fetch, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to `fetch()` Stripe's API to create a payment token directly from the front-end with React Native.

I'm doing so with the following:

```
  const genCard = {
    'card[number]': "4242424242424242",
    'card[exp_month]': "11",
    'card[exp_year]': "25,
    'card[cvc]': "111"
  }

  var formBody = []
  for (var property in genCard) {
    var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property)
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(genCard[property])
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue)
  }
  formBody = formBody.join("&")

  const result = fetch("https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc",
    },
    body: formBody
  }).then(response => response.json())

  console.log('logging: \n', genCard, '\n', formBody, '\n', result)
```

The logging output gives me the following:

```
logging: 
 {"card[cvc]": "111", "card[exp_month]": "11", "card[exp_year]": "25", "card[number]": "4242424242424242"} 
 card%5Bnumber%5D=4242424242424242&card%5Bexp_month%5D=11&card%5Bexp_year%5D=25&card%5Bcvc%5D=111 
 {"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}
```

`genCard` contains all the CC data required by Stripe (number, exp_month, exp_year, cvc), and `formBody` formats the CC data in accordance to all the documentation and guides I've found online. However, the API response I'm receiving is not the expected payment token, but instead `{"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}`.

I believe I've followed Stripe's documentation, but either the header data is incorrect or the body data is mis-formatted.

Is anybody familiar with this process? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody interested, the following solution worked:

```
async function testStripe() {
  const genCard = {
    'card[number]': "4242424242424242",
    'card[exp_month]': "11",
    'card[exp_year]': "25,
    'card[cvc]': "111"
  }

  const results = await fetch("https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc",
    },
    body: Object.keys(genCard)
      .map(key => key + '=' + genCard[key])
      .join('&'),
  }).then(response => response.json())

  console.log('\n\n\nlogging: \n', genCard, '\n', 'blank', '\n', results)

  return
}
```

1. Wrap your `fetch` in an `async` function and `await` the results
2. The `fetch` `body` must be `key->value` pairs of the card data
3. Use your `Stripe Publishable Key` to authenticate api requests

Your api response should look something like this:

```
{"card": {"address_city": null, "address_country": null, "address_line1": null, "address_line1_check": null, "address_line2": null, "address_state": null, "address_zip": null, "address_zip_check": null, "brand": "Visa", "country": "US", "cvc_check": "unchecked", "dynamic_last4": null, "exp_month": 11, "exp_year": 2022, "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c", "funding": "credit", "id": "card_1INjaU2eZvKYlo2C5O5qqIFW", "last4": "4242", "metadata": {}, "name": null, "object": "card", "tokenization_method": null}, "client_ip": "66.42.75.92", "created": 1614020214, "id": "tok_1INjaU2eZvKYlo2CDjL8bde4", "livemode": false, "object": "token", "type": "card", "used": false}
```